# In R3 space, are all vectors on a plane orthogonal to a vector perpendicular to the plane, or just the one vector that intersects it at a point?

Tags: vectors, 3d, orthogonality

If two non-collinear vectors A and B lies on plane Z, and vector C is perpendicular to plane Z and intersects vector B at a point on plane Z, vectors C and B are orthogonal. But are vectors C and A also orthogonal even if they don't intersect at a point?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried taking the dot product of some examples?

Comment: In the picture I just added to the question, vector C is (0, 0, 3) and vector B is (0, 3, 0). But how do I define vector A since it's not going through the (0, 0, 0) point of origin? Doesn't the dot product need all three vectors to be intersecting through the 0 point?

Comment: A vector is specified by it's magnitude and direction. So if you draw a line segment from a point on $A$ whose magnitude and direction is same as that of $C$ then the new directed line segment represents the same vector $C.$ So $C$ and $A$ are orthogonal vectors as well since $A$ and $B$ are coplanar and $C$ is orthogonal to $B.$

Comment: oic, haha, I had it totally confused. Re-read what exactly the definition of a vector is. Thanks for the help!